# Bool property show True & False items

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm working on [this website](http://roldskov.sp34k.dk/produkter/cykler/mountain-bikes/specialized/) in Umbraco 7. My problem is the "gender" filtering on the left side which is a `bool` (queryString). This bool is set on each product as a "Is this product for male? - True or False".

- All gender = nothing
- Male = &gender=true
- Female = &gender=false

By default it's set to "All gender", but in the code, it's actually set to `true` as you can see in my code. I would like to show both `true` and `false` products at the same time.

The bool `isMale = true` should be something like `isMale = true && false` if that would make sense.

```
<div id="categoryCollection">

@{
    bool isMale = true;
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedpriceRange) && selectedpriceRange.Contains("-"))
{
    string[] priceArray = selectedpriceRange.Split('-');
    int minPrice = 0;
    int maxPrice = 0;

    if (queryString.Get("gender") != null)
    {
        isMale = bool.Parse(queryString.Get("gender"));
    }

    if (priceArray.Count() == 2 && int.TryParse(priceArray[0], out minPrice) && int.TryParse(priceArray[1], out maxPrice))
    {
        selectedItems.AddRange(productTypes
            .Where(x => x.HasValue("price") &&
            x.GetPropertyValue<int>("price") > minPrice &&
            x.GetPropertyValue<int>("price") < maxPrice &&
            x.HasValue("gender") &&
            x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("gender") == isMale)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize));

        foreach (var item in selectedItems.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))
        {
            /* If pricerange is selected */
            @buildItemProduct(item);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if (queryString.Get("gender") != null)
    {
        isMale = bool.Parse(queryString.Get("gender"));
    }
    selectedItems.AddRange(productTypes.Where(x => x.HasValue("gender") && x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("gender") == isMale));

    foreach (var item in selectedItems.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))
    {
        /* If pricerange is selected */
        @buildItemProduct(item);
    }
}
</div>
```

If you'd like to see my entire code you can see it [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/GBYkV2WGnxaaw5uEyAuapL).

I don't know how to declare the "isMale" to show both true and false products at the same time.

Comment: This sounds like a job for an enum, or at very least a nullable bool.

Comment: The thing is I'm not really comfortable in this code yet. If you have an example of how that would work, I'd be very happy!

Comment: you have 3 cases

 - male & female
 - male
 - female.

so, you have to check each cases separately. false or true statements are not enough to set your filter. if it was, you could only filter by male or female. think about. it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another bool to keep the change minimal:

```
//...
var bothGender = true;
if (queryString.Get("gender") != null)
{
    isMale = bool.Parse(queryString.Get("gender"));
    bothGender = false;
}

if (priceArray.Count() == 2 && int.TryParse(priceArray[0], out minPrice) && int.TryParse(priceArray[1], out maxPrice))
{
    selectedItems.AddRange(productTypes
        .Where(x => x.HasValue("price") &&
        x.GetPropertyValue<int>("price") > minPrice &&
        x.GetPropertyValue<int>("price") < maxPrice &&
        x.HasValue("gender") &&
        (bothGender || x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("gender") == isMale)) // <-- changes here
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize));

//...
```

Or use an enumeration.

Comment: For slightly cleaner code, you could initialize `bothGender` to `true`, set it to `false` inside the `if` block, and skip the `else`.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I accidentally check without having a priceRange selected. This works like a charm, thank you Thomas, I learned something new today. I credited you here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/templates-partial-views-and-macros/82026-bool-property-show-true-false-items